# How do I write a telegram bot using 'inline_keyboard' (PHP)?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm using 'inline_keyboard' in my php telegram bot, but it is not working.

I tried the same code with 'replyKeyboardMarkup' and it worked perfectly; so guess there is something wrong with this part of the code but I can't find the problem.

```
$inlineKeyboardMarkup = [
  'inline_keyboard' => [
      [
        ['text'=>'text1','callback_data'=>$i],['text'=>'text2','callback_data'=>$i]
      ],
      [
        ['text'=>'start','callback_data'=>$i-(2*$i)]
      ]
    ]
  ];
 $inline_keyboard = json_encode($inlineKeyboardMarkup);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$keyboard = array(
        array(
          array('text'=>'text1','callback_data'=>"1")
          ,array('text'=>'text2','callback_data'=>"2")
        ),
        array(
          array('text'=>'start','callback_data'=>"4")
        )
      );
    $inlineKeyboardMarkup = array(
      'inline_keyboard' => $keyboard
    );
     $data["reply_markup"] = json_encode($inlineKeyboardMarkup);`